# How many watts to power my POE camera?

Tags: power-supply, poe

I have a couple of IP cameras at my home. Brand/Model is EMINENT 6355. They work well with the provided injector.

To avoid having a lot of injectors, I bought a switch LINKSYS LGS108P-EU (POE+.)

The problem is that when I plug the camera in to the POE port of my switch, the camera doesn't work.

The datasheet of the camera says this:

> **LAN/Power – this is a combined connector LAN and power, the camera is powered with the supplied PoE injector. The power needed for this EM6355 is 12V/1A, please make sure you are using the correct power adapter.**

In the switch datasheet I only found this:

> **PoE+ Total Budget: 50W**

Standards : **IEEE 802.3, 802.3 u, 802.3x, 802.3ab, 802.3az, 802.3af, and 802.3at (PoE+)**

I suppose there is not enough power. In this case how many watts are needed to power my cameras?

Comment: Incompatible voltage, inability to negotiate.

Comment: @Andyaka You mean my switch is 220 Volts vs 12 Volts for my cameras ?

Comment: the standard POE+, as mentioned here [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Standard_implementation), provides 42.5V up to 57V for a powered device. maybe the  camera doesn't stick to standards

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad Camera looks to work with 12Volts. So it means that my switch provide too many Volts ?

Comment: Your cameras are incompatible with the IEEE 802.3af and IEEE 802.3at PoE protocols that your switch supports. Your cameras only support passive PoE and do not negotiate their power requirements with your switch. Your switch will simply refuse to power them. I don’t see a solution short of replacing your cameras with more advanced ones.

Comment: @StarCat Thanks for the clarification ! Do you think this device can power up my cameras ? https://www.eurodk.com/en/products/poe-injectors/poe-injector-8-port?currency=EUR&vat_state=incl&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjI7OuN7o6QIV1uR3Ch3DIQPBEAQYAyABEgIbc_D_BwE

Comment: That PoE injector looks simple enough. You would have to make sure it's a "passive" one which will simply deliver 12V to pins 4,5, 7 and 8 of the devices connecting to it. In addition you would also need a suitable 12V power supply.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be the power budget issue. Your camera apparently only needs 12 V × 1 A = 12 W of power, while the lowest PoE option is 13 W (at consumer).

However, PoE transmits power over ethernet cables, which have very thin connectors. Thin connectors have high resistance, and, at such high current (1 A) would cause a lot of energy dissipation and voltage drop. To avoid it, PoE uses relatively high (still human-safe, < 60 V) voltage: at least 37 V, which allows to deliver the same 13 W of power at lower current. (This is the same approach as used to transmit power in the "normal" electricity grid, where up to 500 kV voltage is used to minimize current.)

Now, your camera seems to expect 12 V, which PoE cannot provide, so the camera doesn't work. Unfortunately, the only solution seems to be to use the injector that does what the camera wants.